# how to understand a simplicial complex as a CW structure

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

I learned in my algebraic topolgy course that $X$ is a CW complex if there is a filtration
$$ \emptyset = X_{-1} \subset X_0\subset \dots\subset X_n \subset \dots \subset X $$

such that $X$ is the union of all $X_n$, the topololgy on $X$ coincides with the topology of the filtration and for all $n$, $X_n$ is the push out of the diagram $\sqcup S^{n-1} \to X^n$ and down $\sqcup D^n$. (sorry at the moment I dont know how to make commutative diagrams in Latex). In other words: $X_n = X_{n-1} \sqcup D^n $ where points in $S^n$ are glued to the image in $X_{n-1}$.

Now I'm lacking a bit of examples. We did in class some examples where the professor did everything geometrically i.e saying a circel is aquivalent to take 2 points and two 2 cells. Which is clear intuitvly but doesnt match with tat formal definition I have above. I would like to have some examples worked out really rigoursly. Does anyone has a got reference for that?

Another qustion. My professor said that a simplicial complex i.e a collection of simplicies such that, any intersection is inside and every faces are inside, is also a CW structure. How does this work?

Comment: Since a triangle is homeomorphic with a $2$-ball, a line is homeomorphic with a $1$-ball, a tetrahedron is homeomorphic with a $3$-ball... simplices give a cell structure. Really simplicial structures are like CW structures with data to keep track of how the cells intersect

Comment: There are (at least) three different albeit related notions of what a "simplicial complex" is. You seem to be alluding to the definition of a so-called *geometric* (or Euclidean) simplicial complex: a (locally finite) collection of simplices (convex hulls of finite sets) in some Euclidean space that is closed under taking faces and where any two simplices intersect in a common face. Is this correct?

Comment: @Thorgott yes this is correct, I know also the definition of the abstract simplicial complex, but if I remember my discrete geometry course well, they should be in 1-1 correspondence and so the "same"

Comment: @user1072285 Every geometric simplicial complex gives rise to an abstract simplicial complex (the idea should be contained in my answer), but there are many distinct geometric simplicial complexes giving rise to the same abstract simplicial complex. However, their underlying spaces are all homeomorphic (and homeomorphic to the so-called geometric realization of that abstract simplicial complex). Also, not every abstract simplicial complex (or its geometric realization) arise from geometric simplicial complexes in this way (though it is true for finite complexes).

Answer (score 1):

The notion you are referring to is that of a *geometric* (or Euclidean) simplicial complex. The definitions may slightly vary across the literature, so here's the one I think is best. First, the set-up:

Fix some Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^N$. An $n$-simplex $\sigma^n\subseteq\mathbb{R}^N$ is the convex hull of $n+1$ affinely independent points. These points are uniquely determined by $\sigma^n$ (they are its [extreme points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_point)) and called its *vertices*. In particular, the number $n$ is uniquely determined and called the *dimension* of this simplex. The convex hull of any subset of the vertices of an $n$-simplex $\sigma^n$ yields a $k$-simplex $\tau^k$ for some $k\le n$ that is called a *face* of $\sigma^n$. Every face of $\sigma^n$ that is not $\sigma^n$ itself is called a *proper* face and has strictly smaller dimension; the union of these proper faces is denoted $\partial\sigma^n$. Note that there is an affine linear injection $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}^N$ that maps the standard $n$-simplex $\Delta^n=\{(x_0,\dotsc,x_n)\in[0,1]^{n+1}\vert\sum_{i=0}^nx_i=1\}$ homeomorphically onto $\sigma^n$. In particular, $n\le N-1$. Note also that $\sigma^n$ is necessarily closed (compact even).

Now, a geometric simplicial complex is a family $K$ of simplices in $\mathbb{R}^N$ s.t. (1) a simplex in $K$ also has any of its faces in $K$, (2) two simplices in $K$ are either disjoint or intersect of a common face and (3) the collection is locally finite. The *underlying space* of the geometric simplicial complex is $X=|K|=\bigcup K$, the union of its simplices. There are plenty of low-dimensional examples that can be visualized. I recommend drawing some pictures demonstrating that any polygon or polyhedron can be represented as the underlying space of a geometric simplicial complex by subdividing it into $2$-simplices.

The idea of how to turn a geometric simplicial complex into a CW-complex is fairly intuitive. The $0$-simplices are a set of points, which we take to be the $0$-skeleton. Each $1$-simplex is a line segment joining two $0$-simplices, so we take the $1$-skeleton to be the union of all $0$- and $1$-simplices. Each $2$-simplex is a solid triangle whose edges are $1$-simplices, so we take the $2$-skeleton to be the union of all $0$-, $1$- and $2$-simplices, etc..

Explicitly, given $i=0,\dotsc,N-1$, let $K^i$ be the geometric simplicial complex consisting of all simplices of $K$ that have dimension $\le i$ (exercise: this is actually a geometric simplicial complex) and let $X_i=|K^i|$. This gives an increasing filtration $X_0\subseteq X_1\subseteq\dotsc\subseteq X_{N-1}=X$. In the $i$-th step, the space $X_i$ is, by definition, the union of $X_{i-1}$ and all $i$-simplices $\sigma^i\in K^i\setminus K^{i-1}$. The axiom (1) implies that $\partial\sigma^i\subseteq X_{i-1}$ and axiom (2) implies that $\sigma^i\cap X_{i-1}\subseteq\partial\sigma^i$, so we obtain that $\sigma^i\cap X_{i-1}=\partial\sigma^i$. Furthermore, axiom (2) implies that $\sigma^i\cap\tau^i\subseteq X_{i-1}$ if $\sigma^i,\tau^i$ are *distinct* $i$-simplices. Thus, we obtain a diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\coprod_{\sigma^i\in K^i\setminus K^{i-1}}\partial\sigma^i @>>> X_{i-1}\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\coprod_{\sigma^i\in K^i\setminus K^{i-1}}\sigma^i @>>> X_i
\end{CD}.$$
The previous argument implies precisely that this is a pushout argument on the level of sets. To recognize this as a pushout diagram of topological spaces, it thus remains to argue that a function $f\colon X_i\rightarrow T$ into some topological space $T$ is continuous iff the restrictions $f\vert_{X_{i-1}}$ and $f\vert_{\sigma^i}$ for all $\sigma^i\in K^i\setminus K^{i-1}$ are continuous. This is the case as axiom (3) ensures us that this is a locally finite collection of closed subspaces of $X_i$. Now, you may choose homeomorphisms $D^i\stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow}\sigma^i$ that (necessarily) identify $S^{i-1}\stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow}\partial\sigma^i$ to obtain the desired pushout diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\coprod_{\sigma^i\in K^i\setminus K^{i-1}}S^{i-1} @>>> X_{i-1}\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\coprod_{\sigma^i\in K^i\setminus K^{i-1}}D^i @>>> X_i
\end{CD}.$$
This proves the desired CW-structure.

Note that many spaces are not themselves the underlying spaces of geometric simplicial complexes, but oftentimes homeomorphic thereto. E.g. the sphere $S^1$ is not any such underlying space (simplices are convex and $S^1$ does not contain any convex subspace with more than one point), but it is homeomorphic to $\partial\Delta^2$, a triangle, which can be realized as the underlying space of the geometric simplicial complex consisting of your favorite $3$ points in the plane as $0$-simplices and the $3$ line segments connecting them as $1$-simplices. There are also CW-structures on $S^1$ with $2$ $0$-cells and $2$ $1$-cells as well as $1$ $0$-cell and $1$ $1$-cell, but these do not arise from geometric simplicial complexes in this way.